# Detect 30% from browser window bottom using scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code can detect browser window bottom like below and then run `last_msg_funtion();` :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       last_msg_funtion();
    }
});
```

My problem is user need to scroll down until bottom(*footer*) then `last_msg_funtion();` will run but i want adjust the detection maybe around 30% from bottom

See image below :
[image]

My Site : [Click Here](http://www.micespanel.com/classified.php)

Full Code : [Click Here](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() * 0.7) - $(window).height()){
       last_msg_funtion();
    }
});
```

Note the `* 0.7` will mean that the function will fire when the scroll is 70% of the way down the page - ie. 30% from the bottom.

Comment: i guess your code is correct but idk why it not working after implement with this http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() * 0.7) - $(window).height()){
       last_msg_funtion();
    }
});
```

you have to use `>=` in if condition.

If you use `==` then last_msg_funtion() will call only when scroll is 70% on way.

If you use `>=` then last_msg_funtion() will call only when scroll is greater than 70% on way.

Comment: Just to elaborate further, this is because when javascript does detection for this, it isn't in smooth increments of 1, so if your checking for an exact value, it may or may not get hit.